# Android PackageManager returns different signatures for the same apk

Tags: sha, android-package-managers, android-app-signing

I have an android app which I want to verify its signature at runtime. Here is my code:

```
    @SuppressLint("PackageManagerGetSignatures")
    private boolean validSignature(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),
                            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                final String currentSignature = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
                for (String validSig : validSignatureList)
                    if (validSig.equals(currentSignature))
                        return true;
            }
        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
        }
        return false;
    }
```

For the same APK, on some devices, the APK is verified and on some devices, it's not. When I debug the code, `signature.toByteArray()` has different values on different devices. What am I missing and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: This value does not change, when you are in debug mode it uses the default sign file at "USERPROFILE/.android/debug.keystore" to sign your apk